# Excess Elements Dropdown with Struts2 <s:select/>, aka how to make a dropdown with more elements than allowed on <s:select/>

Tags: struts2

I want to create a dropdown field with all the US territories with Struts2, but the `s:select` property only allows for the inclusion of a few options. I have seen other tutorials create an action that maps to a list and then linking that action to the form but I am already using the form with another action. Ignore any other missing info, everything else works except I am not sure how to create a dropdown with all us territories given the element limit.

formPage.jsp:

```xml
<s:form action="submitForm">    <s:textfield name="firstName" label="First Name"/>    <s:textfield name="lastName" label="Last Name"/>    <s:select name="state" label="State" list="#{'CA':'California', 'NY':'New York', 'TX':'Texas'}" headerKey="" headerValue="-- Select State --" /> </s:form>`
```

inputForm.java:

```
public class inputForm extends ActionSupport{`

    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String state;
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    
    public void validate() {
        if (getFirstName().length() == 0) {
            addFieldError("salutation", "First name is required."); 
        }
        if (getLastName().length() == 0) {
            addFieldError("salutation", "Last name is required."); 
        }
        if (getState().length() == 0) {
            addFieldError("salutation", "State is required."); 
        }
    }

}
```

struts.xml:

```xml
<action name="submitForm" class="Validation.verification.inputForm">            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/verification/results.jsp</result>           <result name="input">/WEB-INF/verification/formPage.jsp</result> </action>
```

Comment: What do you mean "element limit"?

Comment: Select will let me add a few elements in the dropdown options, i.e. a few states, like so: <s:select name="state" label="State" list="#{'CA':'California', 'NY':'New York', 'TX':'Texas'}" headerKey="" headerValue="-- Select State --" />
 But it wont let me add all of the US territories in the same format because it says that is too many dropdown elements.

Comment: Ir is not clear what you asking. It might be infinite number of options. Define your problem.